# Woocommerce - Overwrite global variations with individual variables

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I've got a product that I've created that has 3 options available for it.

- Size of the strap
- Colour of the strap
- Colour of the face

Now each of these are variations, but at the moment, I've got two variations on the product.

- Large size, Any Strap colour, Any Face colour
- Small size, Any Strap colour, Any Face colour

This allows me to change the price for the sizes for all variations.

Now the issue is that I've run out of stock of a particular face, I don't want to remove the variation, but I can't seem to add another variation saying:

- Small Size, Green Strap colour, Any face colour

and make that out of stock, the first ***"small, any, any"*** variation is overwriting this & saying it's in stock.

Is there a way for me to have specific variations out of stock without having to create 170 variations covering all aspects of combinations?

If I run out of blue straps, I'd have to change the stock level of 20 variations!

Answer (score 2):

Drag all global variations at the bottom of your variations, stock will be accounted for with the options, then the price will be set with the last option

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is so simple, i'm surprised it's not documented anywhere else.

For all those who will no doubt find this to be a problem, you're able to set your variations and order them to take priority by simply dragging them to the top of the list for 1st read, and the bottom of the list for last read.

At the top of your variations, put all the products that are out of stock.

- Any Size, Blue Stap, Any Face
- Any Size, Red Stap, Any Face
- Any Size, Any Stap, Red Face

Check **"Manage Stock"** and put the stock to **0** for all these.

Now, lower down your list of variations, put in your global variation (The things you want applying to all the variations you're not setting manually)

- Large Size, Any Colour, Any Colour
- Small Size, Any Colour, Any Colour

Set the prices etc, but ***don't*** *manage stock* on this.

Woocommerce will then use the stock from the first variation, apply that to the product, then set the prices etc for the rest of the variations.